# Invalid use of void expression

Tags: c, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am working on a generic linked list for a class and having problems.

I am getting invalid use of void expression error on this line.

```
freeNode(L->head, L->freeObject( L->head->obj));
```

Here is the prototype for freeNode.

```
void freeNode(NodePtr node, void (*freeObject)(const void *));
```

Here is the struct for `L` (generic linked list).

```
struct list {
    int size;
    NodePtr head;
    NodePtr tail;
    unsigned long int (*compareTo)(void *);
    char * (*toString)(void *);
    void (*freeObject)(void *);
};
```

I know the problem is in with passing what should be a function pointer rather than the output of the function, but I can't figure out what my mistake is.

Comment: I'm felling really dumb now.  I figured it out.  I did not need to try and pass the object that will be passed to the freeObject func.  I changed it to.   freeNode(l->head, L->freeObject);   and it eliminated the error.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This prototype:

```
void freeNode(NodePtr node, void (*freeObject)(const void *));
```

Indicates that the second argument is a pointer to a function that returns `void`. However, the call:

```
freeNode(L->head, L->freeObject(L->head->obj));
```

The second argument is actually the result of calling `L->freeObject(L->head->obj)` which, itself, is simply `void`, not a pointer to function type.

If you want to pass a free function to `freeNode`, then you'd want to pass the pointer to the node as a third argument to `freeNode` and just pass `L->freeObject` as the second argument. So for example, you'd need to call, `freeNode(L->head, L->freeObject, L->head->obj)`. Inside `freeNode` you could then call the function (from the second argument) with the node (third argument). Although without knowing what you want to do inside of `freeNode` and all its use cases, it's unclear what the best approach really is here.